# Unsigned int appears as random negative integer after sending with UDP

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, udp

I send a struct with one field (unsigned int) to a network emulator and it outputs the unsigned int but it is incorrect.

If I do NOT re-run the network emulator, if I resend the struct with the same number, it will be the same random integer. If I send that number +1, I get the random integer -1.

If i do re-run the network emulator and resend the struct with the same number, it shows a different random integer.

This is the stuct:

```
struct pkt_INIT {
  unsigned int router_id;
};
```

This is the code to send that struct:

```
  int sock;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
  struct hostent *host;
  char send_data[1024];

  host= (struct hostent *) gethostbyname(emulator_host);

  if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    perror("socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(emulator_port);
  server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
  bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);

  struct pkt_INIT init;
  init.router_id = router_id;
  strcpy(send_data,(char *)&init);

  sendto(sock, send_data, strlen(send_data), 0,
         (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

I don't have any of the code for the network emulator.

Comment: Your title seems to imply that you're printing an unsigned int and getting a negative number, which is impossible..

Comment: Yeah - I don't know the code for the network emulator but it's supposed to print the unsigned int field of the struct and it's printing negative numbers (When I did it in Java, it printed the correct value).

Comment: Tried running it through `htonl` before sending? Maybe it's supposed to be in network byte order (big-endian).

Comment: It's supposed to be little endian but the professor implied that only people writing in java would have to worry about that. Plus, in that case, no one had negative numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `strcpy()` to put a binary struct into a binary array.  Likewise, do not use `strlen()` to get the length of a struct.  Both functions are designed for strings, and will copy/read bytes until they encounter a null byte.  Use `memcpy()` and `sizeof()` instead:

```
memcpy(send_data, &init, sizeof(init)); 
sendto(sock, send_data, sizeof(init), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

In which case, just get rid of the array and pass the struct directly to `sendto()` instead:

```
sendto(sock, (char*)&init, sizeof(init), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

Now, with that said, there is an issue with the router_id.  Most network protocols require network byte ordering, so you may or may not need to use `htonl()`, depending on what the emulator is actually expecting:

```
init.router_id = htonl(router_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using:   `strcpy(send_data,(char *)&init);`

Is this *really* what you intended to do? You are copying a struct variable to an array of chars. Assuming you want just to do byte-by-byte copy *this* way, there are still problems. *init* won't have NULL termination. So subsequent call to `strlen()` is dubious.

**update:**

Just store -1 in the char array and convert it as integer at the receiver side.

```
send_data[0]=255; //To store -1
send_data[1]='\0';
```

Receiver side:

```
int i;
i = recv_data[0];
```

'i' will have -1.

Comment: The answer is better if you show what to use instead of `strcpy` and how to take the size for `sendto`.

Comment: @Duck had to restart my computer as my system likes to come standstill once in a while :) updated now.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand but the receiver/emulator expects a pkt_INIT struct. And when I add a null character to send_data, I get the same results as before. If I'm sending a struct, is that the same as just sending the integer like in your example?

Comment: you must be using recvfrom() at the receiver side whose signature is same so you could use it like I said. But if that's not the case, you have give us the receiver side code to look to fully understand how it is received so as to get a clear picture of situation.